# Not able to start hbase on Mac OS

Tags: hbase

I installed hbase 1.3.5 using brew and able to start it.
Now I downloaded hbase 2.2.4 and updated the hbase-site.xml as below:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/var/hbase2</value>
  </property>
  <!--<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>-->
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/var/zookeeper2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.dns.interface</name>
    <value>lo0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.dns.interface</name>
    <value>lo0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.master.dns.interface</name>
    <value>lo0</value>
  </property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
   <value>127.0.0.1:2181</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Also change below property in habse-env.sh:

export JAVA_HOME
export HBASE_CLASSPATH
export HBASE_LOG_DIR and
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false

I am starting hbase as ./bin/start-hbase.sh  but getting below error in the logs:

```
ERROR [main] regionserver.HRegionServer: Failed construction RegionServer
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke DNS.getDefaultHost via reflection
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DNS.getDefaultHost(DNS.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.getHostname(RSRpcServices.java:1320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.<init>(RSRpcServices.java:1224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.<init>(RSRpcServices.java:1204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.<init>(MasterRpcServices.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createRpcServices(HMaster.java:720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.<init>(HMasterCommandLine.java:308)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClusterUtil.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.addMaster(LocalHBaseCluster.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.<init>(LocalHBaseCluster.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2955)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DNS.getDefaultHost(DNS.java:60)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.reverseDns(DNS.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.getHosts(DNS.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.getDefaultHost(DNS.java:366)
    ... 25 more
2020-07-30 00:31:15,360 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMasternull
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClusterUtil.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.addMaster(LocalHBaseCluster.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.<init>(LocalHBaseCluster.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2955)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke DNS.getDefaultHost via reflection
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DNS.getDefaultHost(DNS.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.getHostname(RSRpcServices.java:1320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.<init>(RSRpcServices.java:1224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.<init>(RSRpcServices.java:1204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.<init>(MasterRpcServices.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createRpcServices(HMaster.java:720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine$LocalHMaster.<init>(HMasterCommandLine.java:308)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.createMasterThread(JVMClusterUtil.java:132)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.DNS.getDefaultHost(DNS.java:60)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.reverseDns(DNS.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.getHosts(DNS.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.getDefaultHost(DNS.java:366)
    ... 25 more
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful for someone having same issue. Instead of download use brew:
brew update hbase
and change directory path both for
hbase.rootdir and hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir in hbase-site.xml